# How do I change a copy of a Git submodule into a normal Git tree

Tags: git

I just got started working on a submodule of my main project. This submodule is well-supported with a build system that can be used on its own, and test programs that pertain to the module's requirements.

So I took an existing copy of the submodule from the super repo tree and copied it to a new location:

```
cd ~/wip/superrepo
cp -a submodule ../submodule_edit
cd ../submodule_edit
# Do work
git status
fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/submodule
# Aha, it needs its super repo
```

SO is prompting me to consider questions like "How do I unsubmodule a submodule" and so on. I don't want to change this module into a subdirectory of the super repo. The super repo is a collection of modules that are peers in the submodule heirarchy and that's fine. I just want to do this isolated development and it didn't occur to me to clone from the module's own repository when I started.

git submodule deinit is for unregistering a submodule from its parent super repo. I don't need that, and I doubt that it would work since .git in submodule_edit is a dangling pointer to a super repo's metadata.

I sense there is some trivial step that will turn my submodule_edit tree into a normal functioning git sandbox instead of an orphan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submodule *is* a normal repository, *except* ...

- it's controlled by some other Git repository, and
- the repository files (which would normally be in a `.git` directory in the top level of the submodule's work-tree) may have been moved into that other Git repository.

This moving-of-repository-files is called *absorption* and if the Git directory has been absorbed, your `cp -a` did not copy them.  (If the submodule *wasn't* absorbed, your `cp -a` probably worked and you did not ask a question on StackOverflow.)  Instead, the top level of the submodule worktree has a *file* named `.git`, which contains a single line referring to the absorbed-to location.  This line often uses a *relative path:*

```
$ cat submodule/.git
gitdir: ../.git/modules/submodule
```

The relative path may still be valid, in the copied work-tree, or may not.

If you wish to copy the submodule's repository itself, you'll need to do that separately.  Otherwise, you can allow the work-tree copy to refer to the original repository directly, but if you do that, you're entering somewhat dangerous territory.  What is now `git worktree add` used to be a script that did this same kind of thing, and it has a lot of pitfalls.  So you probably should just copy the submodule repository to a new, normal clone, rather than a clone that has been absorbed.

To do *that*, the easiest thing is usually just to re-clone the submodule, using `git clone`.  It's usually easiest in turn to re-clone from the place the original submodule was cloned from.  For instance, if `submodule/.git` exists because `.gitmodules` says:

```
[submodule "submodule"]
    path = submodule
    url = https://github.com/someorg/submodule
```

you should probably just `git clone https://github.com/someorg/submodule` again.

You can, however, clone from the clone your superproject made, which is now in its `.git/modules/submodule` as a bare clone:

```
git clone /path/to/superproject/.git/modules/submodule
```

Either way, you now have a new clone—an independent repository, with an index (where you can assemble a proposed new commit) and a work-tree (where you can see and inspect files in order to assemble the proposed new commit) that is not shared with the repository, index, and work-tree controlled by the superproject, so that the superproject can't wreck any of them.

Comment: I do seem to have an absorbed submodule in the sense that the ophaned "cp -a" copy cannot create branches and has .git as a file with a pointer to the super. The major feature of a "normal git tree" that I want to get back is the relationship between my worktree and the remote, because that is the best way for my work to matter in the future. I think you're saying that I really can't convert my tree into a clone, all I can do is make an actual clone and then maybe I can import my changes with meld or something.

Comment: Well, you *can* complete your `cp` by doing: `rm .git; mkdir .git; cd .git; cp -a <path>/* .` into the place you copied so far, with the `<path>` part coming from where the absorbed repository was. If you had stuff in the work-tree you wanted copied over, that would be a reason to bother with this.